# Não consigo realizar meu dropdown menu

Tags: css, html5, flexbox

Nessa situação não consigo posicionar os elementos `<li>` abaixo de informática de forma responsiva. Estou a fim de criar um dropdown menu mas não faço ideia de como posicionar os `<li's>` abaixo do meu botão informática e então fazê-los aparecerem e desaparecem no hover.

Isso também quebra o alinhamento de todos os outros itens

Se possível execute o código em "Página Toda"

```css
 body{
    background-color: #151515;
}

/* Parâmetros da Navegação */
nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 4.5rem;
    background-color: #232323;
    border-bottom: solid 5px #8B46A3;
}

li, a{
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav-content{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    list-style: none;
    
}

#nav-content li{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 0.70rem;
}
```

```html
 <nav>
        <ul id="nav-content">
            
            <li><svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M21.875 35.9375H6.25C5.4212 35.9375 4.62634 35.6083 4.04029 35.0222C3.45424 34.4362 3.125 33.6413 3.125 32.8125V18.75C3.125 17.9212 3.45424 17.1263 4.04029 16.5403C4.62634 15.9542 5.4212 15.625 6.25 15.625H21.875" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                <path d="M21.875 42.1875H12.5" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                <path d="M40.625 14.0625H34.375" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                <path d="M40.625 20.3125H34.375" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                <path d="M45.3125 7.8125H29.6875C28.8246 7.8125 28.125 8.51206 28.125 9.375V40.625C28.125 41.4879 28.8246 42.1875 29.6875 42.1875H45.3125C46.1754 42.1875 46.875 41.4879 46.875 40.625V9.375C46.875 8.51206 46.1754 7.8125 45.3125 7.8125Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                <path d="M17.1875 35.9375V42.1875" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                <path d="M37.5 37.5C38.7944 37.5 39.8438 36.4507 39.8438 35.1562C39.8438 33.8618 38.7944 32.8125 37.5 32.8125C36.2056 32.8125 35.1562 33.8618 35.1562 35.1562C35.1562 36.4507 36.2056 37.5 37.5 37.5Z" fill="white"/>
            </svg>
            <a href="#">INFORMÁTICA</a> 

                <ul class="ul-submenu">
                    <li class="itemdrop"><a href="#">PEÇAS (HARDWARE)</a>
                    </li>

                    <li><a href="#">PERIFÉRICOS E ACESSÓRIOS</a>
                    </li>

                    <li><a href="#">COMPUTADORES MONTADOS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            
            <li><svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M29.6875 21.0938H35.9375" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                <path d="M14.0625 21.0938H20.3125" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                <path d="M17.1875 17.9688V24.2188" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                <path d="M33.5973 10.8867L16.4071 10.9375C14.0193 10.9377 11.7078 11.779 9.87845 13.3137C8.0491 14.8484 6.8188 16.9784 6.40351 19.3299L6.40518 19.3302L3.209 35.7682C3.00712 36.9136 3.17564 38.0935 3.69007 39.1366C4.2045 40.1797 5.03806 41.0317 6.06968 41.5687C7.1013 42.1057 8.27727 42.2999 9.42679 42.1231C10.5763 41.9462 11.6395 41.4075 12.462 40.5852L12.4617 40.5849L20.9061 31.25L33.5973 31.1992C36.2909 31.1992 38.8742 30.1292 40.7789 28.2245C42.6836 26.3199 43.7536 23.7366 43.7536 21.043C43.7536 18.3494 42.6836 15.7661 40.7789 13.8614C38.8742 11.9567 36.2909 10.8867 33.5973 10.8867V10.8867Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                <path d="M43.5993 19.2793L46.7928 35.7682C46.9947 36.9136 46.8262 38.0935 46.3118 39.1366C45.7973 40.1797 44.9638 41.0316 43.9322 41.5687C42.9005 42.1057 41.7246 42.2999 40.575 42.123C39.4255 41.9462 38.3623 41.4075 37.5398 40.5851L37.5402 40.5848L29.1016 31.2172" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
            </svg><a href="#">CONSOLES</a></li>
            
            <li><svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M25 31.25C31.9036 31.25 37.5 25.6536 37.5 18.75C37.5 11.8464 31.9036 6.25 25 6.25C18.0964 6.25 12.5 11.8464 12.5 18.75C12.5 25.6536 18.0964 31.25 25 31.25Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
                <path d="M6.05249 42.1857C7.97351 38.8606 10.7357 36.0996 14.0616 34.18C17.3876 32.2605 21.1601 31.25 25.0002 31.25C28.8403 31.25 32.6128 32.2606 35.9386 34.1803C39.2645 36.0999 42.0267 38.8609 43.9476 42.1861" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
            </svg>
            <a href="#">SUPORTE</a></li>
            
            <li><svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M17.1875 31.25C22.7966 31.25 27.3438 26.7029 27.3438 21.0938C27.3438 15.4846 22.7966 10.9375 17.1875 10.9375C11.5784 10.9375 7.03125 15.4846 7.03125 21.0938C7.03125 26.7029 11.5784 31.25 17.1875 31.25Z" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
                <path d="M30.354 11.3158C31.7509 10.9222 33.216 10.8326 34.6504 11.0529C36.0849 11.2732 37.4555 11.7983 38.67 12.5929C39.8844 13.3876 40.9145 14.4332 41.6908 15.6594C42.4671 16.8856 42.9716 18.264 43.1703 19.7016C43.3691 21.1393 43.2574 22.6028 42.8429 23.9936C42.4284 25.3845 41.7207 26.6704 40.7674 27.7646C39.8141 28.8589 38.6373 29.7362 37.3164 30.3375C35.9955 30.9387 34.5611 31.2498 33.1098 31.25" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                <path d="M3.12427 38.554C4.71047 36.2978 6.81624 34.4563 9.26382 33.1851C11.7114 31.9138 14.4289 31.2501 17.1869 31.25C19.945 31.2499 22.6625 31.9134 25.1102 33.1844C27.5579 34.4555 29.6638 36.2968 31.2502 38.553" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                <path d="M33.1099 31.25C35.8681 31.248 38.5863 31.9107 41.0342 33.1819C43.482 34.4531 45.5875 36.2955 47.1724 38.553" stroke="white" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
            </svg>
            <a href="#">QUEM SOMOS</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Position: relative;

Tente usar a posição relativa, isso torna o posicionamento absoluto ficar de acordo com o tamanho do pai (que nesse caso é a li que engloba o submenu).

Adicione o CSS abaixo:

```
#nav-content > li {
    position: relative; 
    /* com o position: relative; tudo que tiver dentro da li, vai levar em consideração seu tamanho para se posicionar */
}

#nav-content > li:hover .ul-submenu {
    opacity: 1;
}

.ul-submenu {
    /* com o position: absolute; você poderá posicionar o submenu de acordo com com o tamanho da li (seu pai) lembrando que para isso, é necessário o position: relative; no seu pai (li no caso) */
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: max-content;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```